# Presenting UINavigationController several views deep, as initial view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I would like to have an initial screen which allows the user to sign up for a (web-based) service. Once they have done this, they will automatically log in. These screens will be presented as views within a UINavigationController, something like:

```
1.Opening view > 2.Sign up view > 3.Logging in view > 4.Logged in view
```

Once they have signed up, the next time the app is launched, the app should go straight to view 3 (logging in). How would I present this view as the initial one? 
(an additional question - how would I return to view 1 from view 4 if the user decides to log out?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal answer (to "how to change initial view?") would be to alter you app delegate:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    if ( newuser )
    {
        [window addSubview:viewController1.view];
    } else {
        [window addSubview:viewController2.view];
    }
}
```

with two UINavigationControllers in your xib file. But this may feel a little unorthodox and give rise to other issues. Otherwise, instantly push the whole viewcontroller stack on it, by having your viewcontrollers 1 and 2 immediately push the next controllers without animation.

The user will then just see the "Logging in view". If you decide to let the user pop views 4 and 3 off the stack, viewcontroller 2 will appear.

You can pop the entire stack by calling something like `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]`

Comment: do you mean have some sort of boolean in the first 2 views, which if YES pushes the next view immediately in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines. You could also push them from your app delegate in applicationDidFinishLaunching, so the view controllers will not be cluttered with too much business-logic. There are several ways to either push or set viewcontrollers.

Comment: thanks. what would be the best way to push a couple of screens forward in the app delegate? Currently I just have [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view]; [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: I think just calling `[navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2,nil] animated:NO]` is the best way to go.

Comment: Quoting apple.com UINavigationController docs: "*Discussion
You can use this method to update or replace the current view controller stack without pushing or popping each controller explicitly. In addition, this method lets you update the set of controllers without animating the changes*, **which might be appropriate at launch time** *when you want to return the navigation controller to a previous state."* geez it's all just there...